# Test function that only fires an event

Tags: solidity, remix

I have the following function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18; 

contract PromoContract {
      uint256 public promoCreatedCount;

      function createPromoPerson(address _owner, string _name, uint256 _price) public onlyCOO {
        require(promoCreatedCount < 5000);

        address personOwner = _owner;
        if (personOwner == address(0)) {
          personOwner = cooAddress;
        }

        if (_price <= 0) {
          _price = startingPrice;
        }

        promoCreatedCount++;
        _createPerson(_name, personOwner, _price);
      }
}
```

I started the following Test Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/PromoContract .sol";

contract TestCryptoSportsToken {
    PromoContract promoContract = PromoContract (DeployedAddresses.PromoContract ());
    //check for events

    // Testing the adopt() function
    function testCreatePromoPerson() public {
      promoContract.createPromoPerson("0xf7ca47eabf0e98af942fa45a5e8cdc05b7100eb4", "Test Person", 1);

//check for ?
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to test the contract function `createPromoPerson`. I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the first event from logs which you get in your tx receipt:

```
it("should show the transfer event", function() {
  var token;
  return Token.deployed().then(function(instance){
    token = instance;
    return token.transfer(accounts[1], 100000);
  }).then(function(result){
    console.log(result.logs[0].event)
  })
});
```

This particular test will print to console the name of the triggered event and pass the test.

---

Code from [Smart Contract Unit Testing](https://medium.com/taipei-ethereum-meetup/smart-contract-unit-testing-use-erc20-token-contract-as-an-example-d150c2700834)

---

Another way will be to just check the length of logs:

```
assert.equal(result.logs.length, 1, "No events were triggered.");
```

Comment: Thx for your fast reply! Would you be so kind to write your code in solidity, cause I think it might be extremely interesting to see this testing on solidity code?

Comment: @Kare you can't see events in Solidity. They are only accessible in the logs which are part of the transaction. Hence you have to check if the events were triggered in js (or in any other language you are writing tests).